# Sequelize in Node/Express - 'no such table: main.User` error

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to build a simple Node/Express app with Sequelize, but when I try to create a new record in my relational database, I am getting the error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: main.User`.  Basically, I create a user in the `Users` table and then try to create a related address in the `Addresses` table - the user is successfully created but it fails with this error when creating the address... where is it getting the `main` prefix from in the table name? (full error readout below)...

First off, here's a rundown of my program...

- My Sequelize version is `Sequelize [Node: 6.8.1, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.29.0]`, and I used the Sequelize CLI command `sequelize init` to set up this portion of my project.
- I am using SQLite3 for local development, and in `config/config.json` I have the development db defined as

  ```
  "development": {
      "storage": "dev.sqlite",
      "dialect": "sqlite"
  }
  ```
- My user migration:

  ```
  'use strict';
      module.exports = {
          up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
              return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
                  id: {
                      allowNull: false,
                      autoIncrement: true,
                      primaryKey: true,
                      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                  },
                  first_name: {
                      type: Sequelize.STRING
                  },
                  last_name: {
                      type: Sequelize.STRING
                  },
                  createdAt: {
                      allowNull: false,
                      type: Sequelize.DATE
                  },
                  updatedAt: {
                      allowNull: false,
                      type: Sequelize.DATE
                  }
              });
          },
          down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
              return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
          }
      };
  ```
- and the address migration (abbreviated):

  ```
  module.exports = {
      up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
          return queryInterface.createTable('Addresses', {
              id: {
                  allowNull: false,
                  autoIncrement: true,
                  primaryKey: true,
                  type: Sequelize.INTEGER
              },
              address_line_one: {
                  type: Sequelize.STRING
              },
              UserId: {
                  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                  allowNull: false,
                  references: {
                      model: "User",
                      key: "id"
                  }
              }
          })
      }
  ```
- The user model:

  ```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      var User = sequelize.define('User', {
          first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
          last_name: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {
     classMethods: {
         associate: function(models) {
             models.User.hasOne(models.Address);
         }
      }
   });
  return User;
  };
  ```
- and the address model:

  ```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      var Address = sequelize.define('Address', {
          address_line_one: DataTypes.STRING,
          UserId: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {
          classMethods: {
              associate: function(models) {
                  models.Address.hasOne(models.Geometry);
                  models.Address.belongsTo(models.User, {
                      onDelete: "CASCADE",
                      foreignKey: {
                          allowNull: false
                      }
                  });
              }
            }
        });
   return Address;
   };
  ```
- finally, my route `index.js`:

  ```
  router.post('/createUser', function(req, res){
      var firstName = req.body.first_name;
      var lastName = req.body.last_name;
      var addressLineOne = req.body.address_line_one;

      models.User.create({
          'first_name': newUser.firstName,
          'last_name': newUser.lastName
      }).then(function(user){         
          return user.createAddress({
              'address_line_one': newUser.addressLineOne
      })
  })
  ```

So when I try to post to `/createUser`, the User will successfully be created and the console will say that a new Address has been created (`INSERT INTO 'Addresses'...`), but the address is NOT created and the following error is logged:

`Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: main.User
    at Query.formatError (/Users/darrenklein/Desktop/Darren/NYCDA/WDI/projects/world_table/wt_test_app_1/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:348:14)
    at afterExecute (/Users/darrenklein/Desktop/Darren/NYCDA/WDI/projects/world_table/wt_test_app_1/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:112:29)
    at Statement.errBack (/Users/darrenklein/Desktop/Darren/NYCDA/WDI/projects/world_table/wt_test_app_1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:16:21)`

I've done this sort of thing with Sequelize once before a few months ago and it was successful, I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm missing here.  Why is the app looking for `main.User`, and how can I get it to look for the correct table?  Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aha! A small error has derailed my entire operation. In the migration files, `references.model` must be pluralized!

```
references: {
    model: "Users",
    key: "id"
}
```

Boom.

Comment: if you dont want to worry about pluralization, you can add the option: 'freezeTableName: true' to your table

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen That is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me.

In my development and production database, I use MySQL; it seems to be that for MySQL you can use `references.model` and `references.id` the name of the model and the field in the model.

Locally I started to use SQLite for testing, and that doesn't work. It requires for you to indicate the table name and field exactly as it is in the referenced table.